# github vulnerable dependencies per branch

Tags: github, dependencies

It seems to me that you can only see the vulnerable dependencies on the `master` branch. I fixed those mentioned in the alert on a separate branch and want to check if in fact the vulnerable dependencies are fixed, so what I really need is to be able to check the alert for the specific branch, can this be done?

Answer (score 10):

#### I had this same issue.

The problem with GitHub's Security Alert feature is that it will always scans the default branch of a repository. This is normally the master branch. Therefore, any changes to resolve security issues made to other branches will not be recognised by GitHub.

#### The workaround.

You can change the default branch to be any branch in your repository! **Including the one you have done the work to resolve the security issues**.

1. On GitHub, navigate to the main page of the repository.
2. Under your repository name, click Settings.
3. In the left menu, click Branches.
4. Choose the new default branch.

Once you have changed the default branch to the branch you have done the resolving work on, GitHub's Security Alert feature will start to scan that branch.

And you should see the security alerts that you have resolved disappear.

Afterwards you can change the default branch back to the master branch and only change it when you are specifically working on resolving security vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 8):

The [security alerts for vulnerable dependencies](https://help.github.com/articles/about-security-alerts-for-vulnerable-dependencies/) reported by GitHub might be valid only for the default branch (usually `master`, but [you can change it](https://help.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/setting-the-default-branch)).

If you are not ready to merge your fix to the default branch of your repo, one workaround would be to push that branch to the default (again, usually `master`) branch of a *new* dedicated (and temporary) repository, just to check if any new alerts are detected on that new repo.

Update Oct. 2020, 2+ years later: [Michael Greisman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1470133/michael-greisman) points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50450604/github-vulnerable-dependencies-per-branch/50452145?noredirect=1#comment114245340_50452145) to this [GitHub Community answer](https://github.community/t/how-to-resolve-security-warnings/1385/2) and the documentation "[About alerts for vulnerable dependencies](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/managing-security-vulnerabilities/about-alerts-for-vulnerable-dependencies#investigating-and-resolving-a-vulnerability-in-a-dependency)".

It confirms that the scan is done against the default branch.

> "Once the fix... is merged into the default branch... GitHub will schedule a new scan of your project’s dependencies".

Comment: Not necessarily `master` branch. The scan is done against the repository's *default* branch.

Comment: @JaanusVarus Thank you, that would make sense. I just cannot seem to find a confirmation in https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-security-vulnerabilities/about-security-alerts-for-vulnerable-dependencies and related GitHub help pages.

Comment: Their documentation is lackluster indeed. My comment is based just on an observation of a personal repo.

Comment: @VonC [This GitHub Support Community answer](https://github.community/t/how-to-resolve-security-warnings/1385/2) from a GitHub staffer (lee-dohm) confirms that the scan's done against the default branch. "Once the fix... is merged into the default branch... GitHub will schedule a new scan of your project’s dependencies."

Comment: @MichaelGreisman Thank you, good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.