# github security alerts on more than master branch

Tags: github

I would like to configure my github repository such that I can receive security alerts if a vulnerability is detected on any branch, not just the master branch.  Does anyone know how and where to make this configuration.

The workflow we use to introduce new changes to our project is the following

1. Create a feature branch to develop a change
2. By way of pull request, merge the feature branch changes into a develop branch
3. Build a test instance of the application from the develop branch
4. Verify the change in the test instance
5. Cherry pick the change from the develop branch.
6. Deploy the production instance from master branch

in a recent change we introduced a security vulnerability and we only received a github alert when the change was cherry-picked to the master branch.  Can I configure github to do security scans on all the branches, or perhaps the develop branch along with master?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like my question was previously asked, and there is an answer here: [github vulnerable dependencies per branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50450604/github-vulnerable-dependencies-per-branch)

GitHub security scans occur on the default branch of a repository.